# Eliminate an expression with Mod operation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The `target` below should equal 0, since `2x + c = a + b + c = 6c`,  and `Mod[6c,3] == 0`

But Mathematica seems to be unable to simplify this expression containing `Mod`?

It says `"target-1/4\ Mod[c+2\ x,3] is not a well-formed equation."`

```
Eliminate[{a == b + c, b == 2 c, a == x + y, b == x - y, 
  target - 1/4 Mod[2 x + c, 3]}, {x, a, b, y}]
```

Comment: Could use `GroebnerBasis` with a `Modulus`: In[304]:= 
pols = {-a + b + c, -b + 2 c, -a + x + y, -b + x - y, 
   4*target - (2 x + c) + 3*k};
GroebnerBasis[pols, target, {a, b, c, x}, Modulus -> 3]

Out[305]= {target}

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Eliminate[{a == b + c, b == 2 c, a == x + y, b == x - y, 
  target == 1/4 (2 x + c), Modulus == 3}, {x, a, b, y}]
```

which returns `Modulus == 3 && target == 0`.